# Message queue per user

Tags: mysql, queue

I am using the same user to connect 4 servers to a database.

Although the database is not overloaded, I think that if a heavy query delay occurs on one server, the other servers are affected, especially for new connections.

Mysql server accepts up to 4030 simultaneous connections and has no query limits per user.

Does Mysql queue the queries of the same user or those of all?

If I create a mysql user for each server will I better optimize user queries and queues?

Thank you so much.

Comment: "Sleep" does not matter.  But more than a few dozen _active_ simultaneous connections will bog down the server.  If that is your case, please provide more details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQL does not queue queries for the same user. Each connection, regardless of the MySQL user, has its own thread in `mysqld` (unless you use the thread pool plugin, but that's a separate conversation), and the MySQL Server allows any thread to start a query at any time. It'll do its best to handle all the threads, by using OS thread scheduling. It would do the same thing if you have a single MySQL user for all threads, or a distinct MySQL user for each thread.

It's actually typical in many applications I've seen that the client connects to the MySQL Server using a single MySQL user credential. There is no queuing by user, though it is possible to run so many concurrent queries that they may queue up against each other for access to some shared resources like CPUs or locks. That has nothing to do with which MySQL users are used.

MySQL does support options for setting resource limits per user (see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/user-resources.html), but I have not seen this feature used except in shared hosting environments.

Answer (score 0):

ok thanks
But actually, the 4 servers do not make web requests (open/close connection on each php request). It is about 1 php process for each server, with 6 forked children, each child maintains the same connection for 60 seconds.
I think it would be similar to a persistent connection but every 60 seconds our script refreshes.

This was done to accumulate requests without having to create new connections on each one, but without the drawbacks of a persistent connection.

In this case, is there a queue? I imagine that yes, the same connection is used for 60 seconds.

On the other hand, the mysql server is 0.2 ms away from the other 4 servers.
It might be better to create a new connection and close it for each query? Or better a native MYSQL persistent connection (not made by me)?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Please edit the question to add more details

Comment: There is effectively a queue on a given connection, because you can only execute one query at a time on a single connection. But that's not queuing per user. You could in theory have 400 servers, each running queries concurrently, and they wouldn't block each other. But each one could run only one query at a time.